# a person with disability

Tags: vocabulary

In the USA, the UK, and other parts of Europe which of the following is acceptable and which one  is offensive, from all three perspective (legal, moral and cultural)?

A.  Disabled

B.  Physically challenged

C.  Differently abled

D.  Physically impaired

Comment: They do not all mean the same so perhaps you should edit to give us more context about the people to whom you wish to apply them.

Comment: When I was working, it was considered more appropriate to refer to _people with disabilities_ rather than _disabled people_ or _the disabled_.

Comment: I'm asking about a person with any physical disability. Like, calling someone "deaf" is offensive. We may perhaps say "hearing impaired"??? A person whose leg isn't normal, what should we say? Which of the mentioned in OP is correct?

Comment: I don't know which bug some ppl in this community here have that they give a minus to the question they don't like, regardless the need OP has to know about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Disabled"  This is a simple and generally non-offensive word. But use it as an adjective "disabled people" or "People with disablities".  Don't use it as a noun. Don't talk about "the disabled".

Physically challenged/differently-abled.  These strike me as being ill-thought-through alternatives.  A profoundly deaf person doesn't find hearing challenging (which seems to imply that they should just 'try harder'), and being deaf doesn't magically give you any different abilities.

"Physical impaired" is a category of disablities.  You could use this as "people with physical impairments". Again, don't use "the physically impaired". Other categories are mental impairments, visual impairments, and hearing impairments.

The [Disability Resource Centre at the University of Cambridge](https://www.disability.admin.cam.ac.uk/about-drc/etiquette) gives the following advice:

> Using appropriate language is polite and promotes equality; using
> inappropriate language causes offence. Unfortunately, there are still
> some traps to fall into, as even some disabled people are
> inconsistent, or they might appropriate for themselves, language that
> others no longer use: ‘crips’ or ‘cripples’ for example. Here are some
> guidelines:
>
> - Don't use ‘the disabled’ or ‘the blind’, this defines people by their    impairment and implies that members of these groups are all
>   the same;    do use ‘disabled people’, ‘blind’, or ‘visually impaired
>   people’
> - Medical terms (‘spastic’, ‘quadriplegic’ for example) don't reflect    people's abilities; they may reflect negative attitudes. If a    person's condition needs to be referred to, then they are ‘a
>   person with dyslexia’ or whatever
> - Disabled people are not ‘abnormal’;    non-disabled people are not    ‘normal’
> - Disabled people are not ‘brave’,    ‘afflicted’, ‘victims,’    or ‘tragic’, and they don't ‘suffer’ from    anything, but they do
>   experience discrimination and other negative    attitudes
> - People with mental health problems aren't ‘loonies’ or    ‘schizos’
> - People with learning difficulties are not ‘retarded’,    ‘backward’,    or ‘mentally handicapped’
>
> Don't worry about mistakes, but do be aware of the issue — if in
> doubt, ask a disabled person how they prefer to be described.

Note that "blind people" is not offensive, and by implication "deaf people" is also not offensive, however not every person with a visual impairment is blind. However your use of "A person whose leg isn't normal" could cause offense.

Comment: What about 'special person'? Is that inoffensive? I think it is offensive.

Comment: Special is sometimes used to refer to people with a learning disability (for example the "special Olympics")   But it isn't good to use it of people with a physical impairment, for the same reason as you don't use "abnormal".  In general, simple plain language isn't offensive.  You don't need to avoid words like blind, deaf or disabled".  It is *how* you use them that is important.

Comment: 'hard of hearing' is good, I think.                             
  https://www.washington.edu/doit/how-are-terms-deaf-deafened-hard-hearing-and-hearing-impaired-typically-used

Comment: Yes, good for people who are hard of hearing.  Not good for people who are deaf, as your link states.